# MySQLi INSERT Syntax Error

Tags: php, mysqli

I get this error in my PHP script:

> Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'like, dislike) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' at line 1[`NSERT INTO workouts_likes_by_user (id_from_wall, user_name, like, dislike) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)] in /hermes/bosoraweb110/b720/ipg.workoutlogappcom/android_connect/update_likes.php5 on line 50

This is my query:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO workouts_likes_by_user (id_from_wall, user_name, like, 
dislike) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Thanks.

Comment: You have to insert something in the ? values before passing them to a query.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Syntax error due to using a reserved word as a table or column name in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23446377/syntax-error-due-to-using-a-reserved-word-as-a-table-or-column-name-in-mysql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LIKE` is a [reserved keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html). If you want to use it in your query, wrap them in backticks like so:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO workouts_likes_by_user 
(id_from_wall, user_name, `like`, dislike) 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
```

Of course, not using reserved keywords in your query is the best way, but escaping them using backticks works, too.